# How do you iterate numbers in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Suppose I'd like to print those numbers where I've given inputs.

Here is my program, I want to iterate numbers where I've given the input by using `array`. How do you do it?

```
array = []

num = input("Enter the number of Element: \n")
num = int(num)
array = [num]

print("Enter the", num,"Element: ")

for i in range(0, num):
    myNum = input()
    myNum = int(myNum)
    array += [myNum]

for j in range(array[i]):
    print(j)
```

When I run this, it says:

```
//Output:

Enter the number of Element: 
3
Enter the 3 Element: 
5
6
4
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

What's wrong here?

***EDITED***

Here is my new program:

```
array = []

num = input("Enter the number of Element: \n")
num = int(num)
array = [num]

print("Enter the", num,"Element: ")

for i in range(0, num):
    myNum = input()
    myNum = int(myNum)
    array = [myNum]

for j in array:
    print(j)
```

**//OUTPUT**

```
Enter the number of Element: 
3
Enter the 3 Element: 
4
5
6

6
```

Comment: *"What's wrong here?"* - what do **you think** is wrong?! What were you expecting? `for j in range(array[i])` makes no sense - did you mean `for j in array`?

Comment: "__What's wrong here__" is half way to get your question closed, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify. When you say `array`, do you mean the built-in type `list`, or the actual module named `array`?

Comment: Can you please let me know the correct program to iterate by using array.. I'm having much difficulties here.. :(

Comment: jonrsharpe already told you. `for j in array:`.

Comment: I suggest you find and follow a tutorial. For example: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Thanks but when i iterate value using `for j in array:` it returns *single* last element.. Can you please help me..

Comment: Need sample input and output

Comment: I don't understand "iterate numbers where I've given the input." Can you explain what the program should actually do, and what input and output you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

In your new program you initialize the list `array` with one element that contains the number of loops. I don't think that you want this value in your list.

In the loop you keep overriding the list again and again. You have to `append` the data to the list.

Then you might want to print your message "Enter the x. element" in your loop, not before.

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
array = []
for i in range(num):
    print('Enter the {}. element: '.format(i))
    array.append(int(input())

for j in array:
    print(j)
```